# How can I access Oracle Apex login in my Android app via a rest interface?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a finished Oracle Apex application which is running in browser. Now I want to build a native Android app and access the data that is stored in the Oracle database. 
First I need to authenticate the user with email/password login. 
Second I want to send data to Oracle Apex over rest and store it in the database.
Is there a ready-made function of Oracle Apex that allows me to implement these things?

Comment: you want a native app, or you want an apex app that's mobile friendly? if you already have apex, getting it to be responsive should be much easier than building a net new app from scratch

Comment: I think you have terminology/architecture misunderstandings here. Oracle DB stores your data, including the data that respresents your APEX application. The browser renders the HTML APEX delivered from the DB. You may want a wrapper like Cordova to encase the APEX URL in a native shell, or deploy it as a PWA.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith An apex app would not be native. I already have a finished Browser Apex application and want to access the database of the Apex Browser application from my Android app which I will develop.

Comment: @Scott PWA is out of question for me because the Android app has to work offline and with a PWA I will have problems with cache and performance again. I have not made good experiences with this.  I want a rest of interfaces independent of the Browser Apex application, which I can access from my Android App. For example /getAllUsers returns all users in Json format.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your desired architecture. As described, APEX is very tightly coupled with REST behaviours https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/creating-a-crud-form-on-a-rest-service-with-apex-181

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is what you need: https://ruepprich.wordpress.com/2017/07/25/apex-basic-rest-authentication/

Also you can look at this project:
https://github.com/vincentmorneau/apex-pwa

Comment: Hello Ivan, thanks for your answer. The Auth example is exactly what I was looking for, but I really don't want to use a PWA. So is it possible to define own rest calls? 
E.g. the user fills in a form, clicks on send and I want to store the data in the database.

Comment: Yes, of course. In APEX go to SQL Workshop -> RESTful services. Here you can define your own services and use it in your mobile application. 
Example: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r51/restful_web_services/restful_web_services.html

Also you can write services from scratch. APEX uses Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS), so you can find related documentation, e.g. this: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-create-basic-rest-web-services-using-plsql
It mostly using APEX_JSON package.